# textfields inputAccessoryView my customized pickerview with toolbar - swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipickerview

I have a customized pickerview,and connect two textfields. 
But i have some question with my pickerview.

the pickerview have a toolbar and two barbuttonitems(done & cancel).
 when I click the textfield1. the done & cancel don't have action.
 
then I click the textfield2. the done & cancel don't have action too.
Finally I back to click the textfield1. the button call my cancel & done function successful.
I want to ask what should I do to let my button work in the first click time.

this is code in customized pickerview:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class PickerView: UIView {

var toolbar:UIToolbar       = UIToolbar()
var picker :UIPickerView    = UIPickerView()
var done   :UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
var cancel :UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)

    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    loadContent()
}

func loadContent() {

    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
    toolbar.items = [cancel,flexSpace,done]
    addSubview(toolbar)
    addSubview(picker)
}

}
```

viewcontroller

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController , UIPickerViewDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource {

  var textField1:UITextField = UITextField()  
  var textField2:UITextField = UITextField()  
  var pick1:PickerView = PickerView()
  var pick2:PickerView = PickerView()

    override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    loadElement()
    }

      func loadElement() {

       view.addSubview(textField1)
       view.addSubview(textField2)
    }
     override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

      pick1.picker.delegate = self
      pick1.picker.dataSource = self
      pick2.picker.delegate = self
      pick2.picker.dataSource = self
      textField1.inputView = pick1.picker
      textField1.inputAccessoryView = pick1.toolbar
      textField2.inputView = pick2.picker
      textField2.inputAccessoryView = pick2.toolbar

      //pickerview setting
      pick1.picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
      pick1.picker.tag = 0
      pick1.done.action = #selector(done1Clicked)
      pick1.cancel.action = #selector(cancel1Clicked)

      pick2.picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
      pick2.picker.tag = 1
      pick2.done.action = #selector(done2Clicked)
      pick2.cancel.action = #selector(cancel2Clicked)

    }

    //don't call these functions !!!!!!

    func cancel1Clicked(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {

    textField1.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func done1Clicked(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {

    textField1.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func cancel2Clicked(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {

    textField2.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func done2Clicked(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {

    textField2.resignFirstResponder()
    }

   }
```

Comment: You never set the `target` on the two buttons, only the `action`.

Comment: Thank your advice it's work.